# Trouble using Bootstrap 4 d-flex and d-none class together

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I want to hide a whole `<div>` when adding `d-none` class using jQuery function. But here `.d-none` class not working with `.d-flex` class.

**Before Code**

```
<div class="row d-flex align-items-center ping gatewayBtn reset"> </div>
```

**After Code**

```
<div class="row d-flex align-items-center ping gatewayBtn reset d-none"> </div>
```

I have referred Bootstrap CSS too and found both class use `!important` rule.

I have found an article that says it **won't be overridden.**

Answer (score 0):

CSS works on a "last declared takes precedence" system.

In the bootstrap.css these are defined *in this order*:

.d-none { ...
.d-flex { ...

so the second takes precedence (given all else is equal, such as the `!important` and using the `display:` property).

Note: the order they appear in the element's class list is not relevant, it's the order they are defined in the .css file.

Seen here using bootstrap 4.6, d-flex's `display:` overrides d-none's

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id='div' class='d-flex d-none'>
example
</div>
```

The trick is to redefine `d-none` *after* `d-flex`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
.d-none { display:none !important; }
</style>

<div id='div' class='d-flex d-none'>
example
</div>
```

This *could* be done by editing bootstrap.css, but that's generally not recommended.

You would normally add a `d-none` definition to your `site.css` and include site.css after all the other css's - it's in a `<style>` tag above as the SO snippets put the css block before the html, so would not override it.

Comment: I think it make sense. Becasue I am using custom css, so I am able to add `.d-none` class in my custom css. Thanks @freedomn-m

Answer (score 0):

I have created one solution too for using jQuery function

```
var class_name = "gatewayBtn";
```

```
$('.'+class_name).toggleClass('d-flex').toggleClass('d-none');
```

I am removing `.d-flex` class before add `.d-none` class.

The reason is `d-flex` class will adjust the column according to the row, but here I want to hide the `<div>` and `d-flex` class is only required when want show content of `<div>` , so `d-flex` class removing before add `d-none` class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a size to the class:

**d-md-flex**

and then it will be active only for the specified size

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Answer (score 0):

All the comments above are correct that d-flex class override the d-none.
I solved this challenge by using d-flex as a style instead of class.

```html
<div class="row align-items-center ping gatewayBtn reset" style="display: flex"> </div>
```

thereafter use javascript to change the style to "display: none".
This should help for those using the .show() or .toggle() js as well.